# Convert number to string php with text

Tags: php

Is there a way to convert a number to a string with text at certain points?

Example:

`700` would be `7 minutes 00 seconds`

`60` would be `60 seconds`

`140` would be`1 minute 40 seconds`

so the 3rd number would add `minutes` and at the beginning of the number would always be `seconds`

I have tried `number_format($score, 2, "minutes ")` and other variations but it seems to not work as I need since `7000` would be 70 minutes and 00 seconds and so on.

Comment: : ) did you try anything yet? The obvious answer to this is "yes".

Comment: You are supposed to have a go, and then bring a coding issue to us for help. Not as you have done which is bring a specification to us and expect us to write your code

Comment: Yes, I have tried `number_format($score, 2, "minutes ") `

Comment: [Here is a good link to learn more about this](https://www.quora.com/PHP-programming-language-How-do-you-convert-an-integer-into-a-string-in-PHP).

Comment: Sorry, I will edit the question to add what I have tried.

Comment: What about `7000`?

Comment: What about `10` also

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, use [substr](http://php.net/manual/it/function.substr.php)

```
function minuteAndSeconds($string) {
    switch (strlen($string)) {
      case 1:
        return '0' . $string . ' seconds';

     case 2:
       return $string . ' seconds';

     case 3:
       return substr($string, 0, 1) . ' minutes ' . substr($string, 1) . ' seconds';

     default:
       return 'Invalid string format';
  }
}
```

the function accepts a string and returns that string formatted in the way you asked.

You have to cast number to string. (eg. `$variable = (string) $variable`)

Comment: And if its `7000` or `20` ??

Answer (score 0):

I think regex is the best option as it can be two or three (?) digit minutes.
This will match two last digits as seconds, and any digits before that as minutes.

```
$n = 700;

Preg_match("/(\d*)(\d{2})/", $n, $match);

Echo ($match[1] ?: 0) . " minutes and ". $match[2] . " seconds";
```

https://3v4l.org/NvaGp

---

Or you can use list() to make each array item a variable.

```
$n = 700;

Preg_match("/(\d*)(\d{2})/", $n, $match);
List($n, $minutes, $seconds) = $match;

Echo ($minutes ?: 0) . " minutes and ". $seconds . " seconds";
```

https://3v4l.org/grWaV